# Remix IDE runs every transaction twice in Remix VM - Mainnet fork (and Testnet forks)

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging, remix-tests

I ran some unit tests in Remix IDE using the Remix VM - Merge. It works without any issues. As I needed the ERC-1820 registry contract I switched to Remix VM - Mainnet fork for the unit tests. Some error indicated that the transactions triggered by the unit tests are executed twice on the Remix VM - Mainnet fork. So I created a very simple contract to check this issue:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract CallCounter {

    uint256 callCounter = 0;

    function call() public {
        callCounter += 1;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Return value 
     * @return value of 'number'
     */
    function retrieve() public view returns (uint256){
        return callCounter;
    }
}
```

Deployed on the Remix VM - Mainnet fork, when triggering the call method with a transacation it always adds 2 to the `callCounter` instead of 1. This contract works perfectly fine on Remix VM - Merge or on a local Ganache blockchain. Is this a known bug in Remix IDE? When using the debugger I can always debug only the second execution of the transaction. Also there is no hash of two transactions. It seems like there is just one transaction sent.

To reproduce:

1. Deploy above contract using Remix on the Remix VM - Mainnet fork
2. call the "retrieve" view -> expected result: 0, actual result: 0
3. call the "call" function
4. call the "retrieve" view again -> expected result 1, actual result: 2

**Remix IDE Versions:** Remix Desktop 1.3.6 on Ubuntu 22.04 and current version deployed on https://remix.ethereum.org used in Firefox

Comment: I am having the same issue while testing the contract.. The constructor in my ERC20 creates a liquidity with WETH, and when I run it in mainnet fork on Remix, i get the PAIR_EXISTS error on uniswap LOL. This is ofcourse impossible as the token is getting created in this constructor so there is no way it exists. After I changed the code to create the new Pair only if it doesn't exists, then it went thorugh, and I can see that the pair does not exist in the mainnet. I was desperate and asked chat gpt and it said to check my deployment scripts if it doesn't run twice. I thought it is hallucinatin